# VBA code to retain TOP 11 Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retain top11 rows (top10 rows plus header) after everytime I filter data and delete the remaining clutters. Can anyone help me????

```
sub macro()
.......
.......
........
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Top10").Range("B1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="fiter1", VisibleDropDown:=True
        Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("J2"), Order1:=xlAscending
        Range("A12:J" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        Worksheets("Top10_WO").Range("B1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="fiter2", VisibleDropDown:=True
        Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("J2"), Order1:=xlAscending
        Range("A22:J" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        Worksheets("Top10_WO").Range("B1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="fiter3", VisibleDropDown:=True
        Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("J2"), Order1:=xlAscending
        Range("A32:J" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.....
....
....(upto filter28)
```

presently I have this code, but this is not flexible as my filtered data range will be dynamic. So I want a code that retains top 10 rows and header and delete remaining all rows for each filtered data(filter 1 to filter 28).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Excel on Windows as you can use SQL to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to conceptualize this code working, as it seems you are overwriting existing data each time.  It may well, it's just hard for me to imagine what your data looks like such that this would work.

That said, if I take your code at face value and assume it does as you expect, but you don't want to hard-code each iteration of the filter, then this code would be an effective replacement for what you did above, for all 28 filters.

```
Sub macro()

  Dim ws, sorts As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow, filter, nextRow As Long
  Dim sortRange As Range

  Set ws = Worksheets("Top10_WO")
  Set sorts = New Worksheet
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  nextRow = 12

  For filter = 1 To 28

    ws.Range("B1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="fiter" & filter, VisibleDropDown:=True
    sortRange.Sort Key1:=Range("J2"), Order1:=xlAscending
    Range("A" & nextRow & ":J" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    nextRow = nextRow + 10

  Next filter

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much HAMBONE.It seems like your code woks for me.I'll just check with it...But In my code filter1 to filter 28 means it could be names of persons or cities or so.....In that case, what to do??? I think i can assign all names to those filters ryt??.....ie filter1=personA filter2=personB and so on....need ur help...again thank you so much that u replied to me so quickly

Comment: I think the easiest way might be to list all of those in another worksheet.  Then, instead of looping 1 - 28, you can loop through the cells in the worksheet, where the filter criteria is defined.  Does this make sense?